# Is there a way to add multiple labels at once to a Gmail thread in a google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I am trying to add some labels to Gmail threads in a google-app script programmatically.

Using [thread.addLabel](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#addLabel(GmailLabel)) function right now. 
Because I am adding multiple labels to many threads, this approach is first slow and second inefficient in quota usage. I have to call thread.allLabel for every label for every thread.

Is there a way to add multiple labels to Gmail threads / messages together? 
The Gmail API has a [thread.modify](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/modify) function that can be used to add multiple labels. Is there something similar in google apps script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add several labels to a thread using Google Apps Script. If my understanding is correct, how about using Gmail API of Advanced Google Services? In GmailApp, I couldn't find methods for adding several labels to a thread. So I propose this. I think that you can achieve it using `gmail.users.messages.modify`. The sample script is as follows. In order to use this script, please enable Gmail API at Advanced Google Services and API console.

#### Enable Gmail API v1 at Advanced Google Services

- On script editor

  - Resources -> Advanced Google Services
  - Turn on Gmail API v1

#### [Enable Gmail API at API console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/gmail.googleapis.com/overview)

- On script editor

  - Resources -> Cloud Platform project
  - View API console
  - At Getting started, click Enable APIs and get credentials like keys.
  - At left side, click Library.
  - At Search for APIs & services, input "Gmail". And click Gmail API.
  - Click Enable button.
  - If API has already been enabled, please don't turn off.

If now you are opening the script editor with the script for using Gmail API, you can enable Gmail API for the project by accessing this URL https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/gmail.googleapis.com/overview

#### Flow of script :

1. Retrieve label list.
2. Retrieve label IDs using label names.
3. Add the labels to a thread.

#### Sample script :

```
var userId = "me";
var threadId = "### thread ID ###"; // Please input a thread ID.
var labels = ["### label name 1 ###", "### label name 2 ###"]; // Please input label names here.

var labelList = Gmail.Users.Labels.list(userId).labels;
var labelIds = labels.map(function(e){return labelList.filter(function(f){return f.name == e})[0].id});
Gmail.Users.Messages.modify({"addLabelIds": labelIds}, userId, threadId);
```

#### Note :

- This is a simple sample script. So please modify it to your environment.

#### References :

- [Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the good suggestion. Where do you see the documentation for the parameters of the `modify` function ? [Gmail API Doc](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/modify) passes only one object to `modify`. Apps Script [sample code](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script/blob/master/advanced/gmail.gs#L48) does not use `modify` but calls `threads.list` with a different set of parameters. The example in your answer is similar to the Apps Script sample but then the order is different. How did you know the expectations of parameters?

Comment: @Hakan Baba I also confirm about how to use ``modify`` at https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/modify In this document, I saw ``addLabelIds[]`` and ``removeLabelIds[]`` for the Property name. These means that the labels can be given as an array. So I could understand how to use it. Also about Advanced Google Services, I could understand from the sample script in the document. Is my understanding for your comment correct?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have asked a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49120851/5771861). Appreciate any further help.