# How to make a Gmail API batch request from google apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail-api

As an example, I need the batch request in the following scenario: 
After using `Gmail.Users.Threads.list(..)` I would like to do several `Gmail.Users.Threads.get(threadId,..)` operations in a batch.

I am talking about something similar to  `gapi.client.newBatch();` call in [javascript gmail api](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/batch).

First in apps script, one needs to enable the Gmail v1 Api in Advanced Google Services as described [here](http://Enable%20Gmail%20API%20v1%20at%20Advanced%20Google%20Services).

Then using the Gmail Api in google apps script looks like this: 
[image: Gmail Api in Google Apps Script]

The suggestions are:

```
Users : UsersCollection
newAutoForwarding() : AutoForwarding
newBatchDeleteMessagesRequest() : BatchDeleteMessagesRequest
newBatchModifyMessagesRequest() : BatchModifyMessagesRequest
newDraft() : Draft
newFilter() : Filter
newFilterAction() : FilterAction
newFilterCriteria() : FilterCriteria
newForwardingAddress() : ForwardingAddress
newImapSettings() : ImapSettings
newLabel() : Label
newLabelColor() : LabelColor
newMessage() : Message
newMessagePart() : MessagePart
newMessagePartBody() : MessagePartBody
newMessagePartHeader() : MessagePartHeader
newModifyMessageRequest() : ModifyMessageRequest
newModifyThreadRequest() : ModifyThreadRequest
newPopSettings() : PopSettings
newSendAs() : SendAs
newSmimeInfo() : SmimeInfo
newSmtpMsa() : SmtpMsa
newVacationSettings() : VacationSettings
newWatchRequest() : WatchRequest
```

There is no `newBatch()` suggested.

Comment: Was my answer useful for you? If you have issues in my answer, feel free to tell me. Such information helps me to study. Also I think that it helps other users to know the situation as an information.

Answer (score 2):

How about this answer? I couldn't find the method of batch request for `Gmail.Users.Threads.get()`. And at Google Apps Script, there are no methods for requesting the batch request. So it is required to implement the method. The flow of batch request is as follows.

1. Create the request body for the batch request.
2. Requst the body to the endpoint of `POST https://www.googleapis.com/batch` using `multipart/mixed`.

   - The access token is required to be used for only this post.

The sample script for this flow is as follows.

### Sample script :

#### Flow :

1. Retrieve thread list using `Gmail.Users.Threads.list()`.
2. Create the request body for `Gmail.Users.Threads.get()`.

   - In this case, `Gmail.Users.Threads.get()` of Advanced Google Services cannot be used, so it is required to directly use the API.
3. Post the created body using `multipart/mixed`.
4. Parse the response.

#### Script :

```
function myFunction() {
  var userId = "me"; // Please modify this, if you want to use other userId.
  var threadList = Gmail.Users.Threads.list(userId).threads;
  var body = threadList.map(function(e){
    return {
        method: "GET",
        endpoint: "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/" + userId + "/threads/" + e.id
    }
  });
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/batch";
  var boundary = "xxxxxxxxxx";
  var contentId = 0;
  var data = "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
  for (var i in body) {
    data += "Content-Type: application/http\r\n";
    data += "Content-ID: " + ++contentId + "\r\n\r\n";
    data += body[i].method + " " + body[i].endpoint + "\r\n\r\n";
    data += "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
  }
  var payload = Utilities.newBlob(data).getBytes();
  var options = {
    method: "post",
    contentType: "multipart/mixed; boundary=" + boundary,
    payload: payload,
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
  };
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText();
  var dat = res.split("--batch");
  var result = dat.slice(1, dat.length - 1).map(function(e){return e.match(/{[\S\s]+}/g)[0]});

  Logger.log(result.length)
  Logger.log(result)
}
```

### Note :

- The parsed response is an array. Each element in the array is corresponding to each element in the request body.
- In this sample script, the thread list is retrieved by `Gmail.Users.Threads.list("me").threads`. If you want to use some threads, please modify the request body.

### Reference :

- [Batching Requests](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/batch)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: what is "Utilities" ?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities