# Javascript fetch fails to read Multipart response from GMail API Batch request

Tags: javascript, http, fetch, multipartform-data, gmail-api

I need to use GMail API to retrieve multiple emails data so I am using [Batch API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch). I could finally craft a good enough request but the problem is Javascript doesn't seem to properly parse the response. Note that this is pure browser Javascript, I am not using any server.

Please refer the code below. The request/response was good upon inspection, but at the line where I call `r.formData()` method, I receive this error with no further explanation:

> TypeError: Failed to fetch

```
    async getGmailMessageMetadatasAsync(ids: string[], token: string): Promise<IGmailMetaData[]> {
        if (!ids.length) {
            return [];
        }

        const url = `https://gmail.googleapis.com/batch/gmail/v1`;

        const body = new FormData();
        for (let id of ids) {
            const blobContent = `GET /gmail/v1/users/me/messages/${encodeURI(id)}?format=METADATA`;
            const blob = new Blob([blobContent], {
                type: "application/http",
            });

            body.append("dummy", blob);
        }

        const r = await fetch(url, {
            body: body,
            method: "POST",
            headers: this.getAuthHeader(token),
        });

        if (!r.ok) {
            throw r;
        }

        try {
            const content = await r.formData(); // This won't work

            debugger;
            for (let key of content) {

            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
            debugger;
        }
        

        return <any>[];
    }
```

If I replace `r.formData()` with `r.text()`, it works but then I have to parse the text by myself which I don't think is good. The response has correct `content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=batch_HViQtsA3Z_aYrPoOlukRFgkPEUDoDh23` and the body looks like this:

```
"
--batch_HViQtsA3Z_aYrPoOlukRFgkPEUDoDh23
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: response-

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Vary: Origin
Vary: X-Origin
Vary: Referer

{
  "id": "1778c9cc9345a9f4",
  "threadId": "1778c9cc9345a9f4",
  "labelIds": [
    "IMPORTANT",
    "CATEGORY_PERSONAL",
    "INBOX"
  ],

<More content>
```

How do I properly parse this response and get the JSON content of each email?

Comment: Hi ! I believe you are not using [FormData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) correctly, please refer to the documentation. Moreover, I dont think ```formData()``` will get you what you want (the JSON objects). Have you tried using [JSON.pase(response)](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp) instead?

Comment: Hi I am sure I am using [`formData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/formData), not the `FormData` you are mentioning (though the result should be of `FormData` type). For JSON.parse unfortunately it does not work immediately because I still need to parse from the response text for that JSON part.

Comment: Note that the text content I posted is the full body text, not just the JSON (because the body content is a multipart containing multiple JSON for each request).

Comment: I believe your main issue is that you are using ```r.formData()``` when actually ```r``` is already a form data object as described from the content type. Have you tried using insread ```r.getAll()``` or any other method such as ```r.entries()``` from the [formData methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)? Also, you dont want to do a string search right? That is why an answer like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49121439/12835757) would not do the job for you right?

Comment: @MateoRandwolf thanks for the response and sorry for late reply, I was working on another project. `r` is NOT `formData` but `Response` (I confirmed it with Javascript too, not just relying on TypeScript). Cannot perform a `for in/of` on `r` (it's not iterable, just a very standard `Response` object). `r` does not have `getAll()` or `entries()` methods. And yes you are right that I want to avoid doing string search (at least by myself). But I would do that if I find no other solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the other answer, I realized the response body is `multipart/mixed`, not `multipart/form-data` so I wrote this parser myself.

```
export class MultipartMixedService {

    static async parseAsync(r: Response): Promise<MultipartMixedEntry[]> {
        const text = await r.text();
        const contentType = r.headers.get("Content-Type");

        return this.parse(text, contentType);
    }

    static parse(body: string, contentType: string): MultipartMixedEntry[] {
        const result: MultipartMixedEntry[] = [];

        const contentTypeData = this.parseHeader(contentType);
        const boundary = contentTypeData.directives.get("boundary");
        if (!boundary) {
            throw new Error("Invalid Content Type: no boundary");
        }
        const boundaryText = "--" + boundary;

        let line: string;
        let pos = -1;
        let currEntry: MultipartMixedEntry = null;
        let parsingEntryHeaders = false;
        let parsingBodyHeaders = false;
        let parsingBodyFirstLine = false;

        do {
            [line, pos] = this.nextLine(body, pos);

            if (line.length == 0 || line == "\r") { // Empty Line
                if (parsingEntryHeaders) {
                    // Start parsing Body Headers
                    parsingEntryHeaders = false;
                    parsingBodyHeaders = true;
                } else if (parsingBodyHeaders) {
                    // Start parsing body
                    parsingBodyHeaders = false;
                    parsingBodyFirstLine = true;
                } else if (currEntry != null) {
                    // Empty line in body, just add it
                    currEntry.body += (parsingBodyFirstLine ? "" : "\n") + "\n";
                    parsingBodyFirstLine = false;
                }

                // Else, it's just empty starting lines
            } else if (line.startsWith(boundaryText)) {
                // Remove one extra line from the body
                if (currEntry != null) {
                    currEntry.body = currEntry.body.substring(0, currEntry.body.length - 1);
                }

                // Check if it is the end
                if (line.endsWith("--")) {
                    return result;
                }

                // If not, it's the start of new entry
                currEntry = new MultipartMixedEntry();
                result.push(currEntry);
                parsingEntryHeaders = true;
            } else {
                if (!currEntry) {
                    // Trash content
                    throw new Error("Error parsing response: Unexpected data.");
                }

                // Add content
                if (parsingEntryHeaders || parsingBodyHeaders) {
                    // Headers
                    const headers = parsingEntryHeaders ? currEntry.entryHeaders : currEntry.bodyHeaders;
                    const headerParts = line.split(":", 2);

                    if (headerParts.length == 1) {
                        headers.append("X-Extra", headerParts[0].trim());
                    } else {
                        headers.append(headerParts[0]?.trim(), headerParts[1].trim());
                    }
                    
                } else {
                    // Body
                    currEntry.body += (parsingBodyFirstLine ? "" : "\n") + line;
                    parsingBodyFirstLine = false;
                }
            }
        } while (pos > -1);

        return result;
    }

    static parseHeader(headerValue: string): HeaderData {
        if (!headerValue) {
            throw new Error("Invalid Header Value: " + headerValue);
        }

        var result = new HeaderData();
        result.fullText = headerValue;

        const parts = headerValue.split(/;/g);
        result.value = parts[0];

        for (var i = 1; i < parts.length; i++) {
            const part = parts[i].trim();
            const partData = part.split("=", 2);

            result.directives.append(partData[0], partData[1]);
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static nextLine(text: string, lastPos: number): [string, number] {
        const nextLinePos = text.indexOf("\n", lastPos + 1);

        let line = text.substring(lastPos + 1, nextLinePos == -1 ? null : nextLinePos);
        while (line.endsWith("\r")) {
            line = line.substr(0, line.length - 1);
        }

        return [line, nextLinePos];
    }

}

export class MultipartMixedEntry {

    entryHeaders: Headers = new Headers();
    bodyHeaders: Headers = new Headers();

    body: string = "";

    json<T = any>(): T {
        return JSON.parse(this.body);
    }

}

export class HeaderData {

    fullText: string;
    value: string;
    directives: Headers = new Headers();

}
```

Usage:

```
        const r = await fetch(url, {
            body: body,
            method: "POST",
            headers: headers,
        });

        if (!r.ok) {
            throw r;
        }

        try {
            const contentData = await MultipartMixedService.parseAsync(r);

            // Other code
```

Someone asked for request and response body, here is an example (I censored the Bearer token and my email):

```
fetch("https://gmail.googleapis.com/batch/gmail/v1", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "*/*",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,vi;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7",
    "authorization": "Bearer <YOUR TOKEN>",
    "content-type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryZ9nvH6zUTGoR7aAs",
    "sec-ch-ua": "\" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"90\", \"Microsoft Edge\";v=\"90\"",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "cross-site"
  },
  "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
  "body": "------WebKitFormBoundaryZ9nvH6zUTGoR7aAs\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"dummy\"; filename=\"blob\"\r\nContent-Type: application/http\r\n\r\nGET /gmail/v1/users/me/messages/1799c0f9031dc75a?format=METADATA\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryZ9nvH6zUTGoR7aAs--\r\n",
  "method": "POST",
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "include"
});
```

```
--batch_jb1MbufS6_fEEIu5e6taSCLa9ZOYifdP
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: response-

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Vary: Origin
Vary: X-Origin
Vary: Referer

{
  "id": "1799c0f9031dc75a",
  "threadId": "1799c0f9031dc75a",
  "labelIds": [
    "UNREAD",
    "SENT",
    "INBOX"
  ],
  "payload": {
    "partId": "",
    "headers": [
      {
        "name": "Return-Path",
        "value": "\u003c******@gmail.com\u003e"
      },
      {
        "name": "Received",
        "value": "from LukePC ([****:***:****:****:d906:d8c4:10f6:6146])        by smtp.gmail.com with ESMTPSA id u6sm8286689pjy.51.2021.05.23.18.48.55        for \u003c******@gmail.com\u003e        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);        Sun, 23 May 2021 18:48:56 -0700 (PDT)"
      },
      {
        "name": "From",
        "value": "\u003c******@gmail.com\u003e"
      },
      {
        "name": "To",
        "value": "\u003c******@gmail.com\u003e"
      },
      {
        "name": "Subject",
        "value": "Test Email"
      },
      {
        "name": "Date",
        "value": "Mon, 24 May 2021 08:48:52 +0700"
      },
      {
        "name": "Message-ID",
        "value": "\u003c000201d7503e$f42b1ea0$dc815be0$@gmail.com\u003e"
      },
      {
        "name": "MIME-Version",
        "value": "1.0"
      },
      {
        "name": "Content-Type",
        "value": "multipart/alternative; boundary=\"----=_NextPart_000_0003_01D75079.A089F6A0\""
      },
      {
        "name": "X-Mailer",
        "value": "Microsoft Outlook 16.0"
      },
      {
        "name": "Thread-Index",
        "value": "AddQPvAK354ufYfSQqqfwTDwp7zDCQ=="
      },
      {
        "name": "Content-Language",
        "value": "en-us"
      }
    ]
  },
  "sizeEstimate": 2750,
  "historyId": "197435",
  "internalDate": "1621820932000"
}

--batch_jb1MbufS6_fEEIu5e6taSCLa9ZOYifdP--
```

Answer (score 3):

I was not able to test your code sample. However [reading the documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch) I see a potential mistake in your code. Indeed you are using a `Content-Type` `multipart/form-data` in your request but according to the Google documentation, you should instead use a **`multipart/mixed`** `Content-Type`. Quoting the doc:

> A batch request is a single standard HTTP request containing multiple Gmail API calls, using the **multipart/mixed** content type. Within that main HTTP request, each of the parts contains a nested HTTP request.

My guess is that the Google API kindly accepts your `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` and returns the same `Content-Type` header in the response **even if the content itself is** probably **not a *form-data***<sup>1</sup> as specified in [RFC7578](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578). It's probably the reason why the [`Response.formData()` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/formData) fails to parse the content.

---

<sup>1</sup> I stay voluntarily cautious because [disclaimer again] I did not test your code and I therefore didn't see the full result of the response.

Comment: That's an interesting point. I tried crafting a `multipart/mixed` request manually (because I see no way to send it using `FormData`), the response indeed has `content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary=batch_bCj2rPNTx_nohFC8LwscDqtbtZIpux37`.  The response text is the same. However calling `r.text()` and `r.formData()` has the same behavior as `multipart/form-data` response :( Guess parsing string is needed for it. I think something is wrong with v8's `formData()` method, because in another client Insomnia, the app could parse the response into multiple parts.

Comment: I don't think there is an issue with fetch API, the goal is to parse `FormData`, here you are giving something else. Indeed the response is a multipart but not a `multipart/form-data`. So for me it makes sense that `formData()` fails if you give it something else.

Comment: Oh sorry I am dumb, I didn't notice `multipart/form-data` body is so different from `multipart/mixed`. Yes I think you are right, somehow Google just copy the request `Content-Type` and gives a `multipart/mixed` body anyway.

Comment: Glad it helped. :-)

Comment: @LukeVo Would you please provide the multipart/mixed request? I am trying to do something similiar with Python, but I just don't manage to get a decent request written. Thanks!

Comment: @Mxngls added the bodies to my answer below.

Comment: Thanks! I somehow managed to get a request out as well! Unfortunately I think I don't pass my credentials in the right way. Could you maybe specify how they need to be passed?