# Script to search for multiple unread labels in Gmail threads at once

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, gmail-api

I have the following structure of labels

```
+------------+------------+---------------+
|   label    | sub-label  | sub-sub-label |
+------------+------------+---------------+
| 01-fruit   |            |               |
|            | 01-apples  |               |
|            |            | green         |
|            |            | red           |
|            | 02-oranges |               |
|            |            | red           |
|            |            | orange        |
| 02-veggies |            |               |
|            | 01-peppers |               |
|            |            | green         |
|            |            | red           |
+------------+------------+---------------+
```

The script in use is:

```
function mail2Sheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('newRec'); //get the sheet
  var freshLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("00-fresh"); // in the end, add this label
  const query = "label:unread" + " label:01-fruit"; 
  var foundThreads = GmailApp.search(query);
  var newReceipts = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < foundThreads.length; i++) {

  +++++++ SOME CODE HERE +++++++

    }
  }
  if(!foundThreads.length) return; //  if there are no unread ones, do nothing.
  sheet.getRange(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow()+1,2,newReceipts.length,newReceipts[0].length).setValues(newReceipts); //write to sheet
  GmailApp.markThreadsRead(foundThreads); // mark "foundThreads" as read
  freshLabel.addToThreads(foundThreads); // add label "00-fresh" to "foundThreads"
  GmailApp.refreshThreads(foundThreads); // refresh "foundThreads" for changes to show
}
```

I can successfully search for a single label like: `const query = "label:unread" + " label:01-fruit";`

Also.
Although I have `GmailApp.refreshThreads(foundThreads);` the `Execution` never completes.
Instead it shows `Status Running`

[image]

### **TO RECAP**

How can I make the query search at the same time for multiple labels like
`"label:unread" + " label:00-fruit/01-apples/red"`
AND
`"label:unread" + " label:02-veggies/01-peppers/red"`

Also. How can the `Status Running` issue be fixed?

Comment: In your case, when you want to search the mails with `label:unread` and `label:00-fruit/01-apples/red`, please use the search query of `label:unread label:00-fruit/01-apples/red`. `" "` which is a space is used as `AND` operator. When you want to search the mails with `label:unread` and `label:00-fruit/01-apples/red` or `label:02-veggies/01-peppers/red`,  please use the search query of `label:unread (label:00-fruit/01-apples/red OR label:02-veggies/01-peppers/red)`. [Ref](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en) But if I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Again from @Tanaike article, this might be useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49065383/11225291

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for the quick reply. Let me check this out. Also. Any idea on why the execution never ends?

Comment: Thank you @Marios . I have seen that link. It suggests to enable Advanced Google Services. I was looking for a way to avoid that. Any idea on why the execution never ends?

Comment: In your situation, the issue of `Status Running` occurs at `GmailApp.refreshThreads`. If my understanding is correct, in my environment, I cannot replicate it. I apologize for this. When I use your script without the for loop, no issue occurs and the script is correctly finished. In your environment, the issue occurs every run?

Comment: @Tanaike *"In your environment, the issue occurs every run?"*. I haven't tried it that many. But most of the times.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, although I tested several times for your script without the for loop, I cannot still replicate your issue. I apologize for this. But for Gmail, I had sometimes had the experience that when the result situations are different between my environment and user's environment under the same script. So in your case, I'm worry about the possibility of it.

Comment: @Tanaike The environment is a new, regular account with only 77 emails and 11 unread messages. I don't see why the script should take so long to execute (5.289 s), as well as not get completed. Also the script is really simple. If you want you can see the [full script here](https://pastebin.com/y9kyj1Sz) and the [execution times here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZjMw.png). The (1.749 s) execution time is without the `refreshThreads` command.

Comment: Side Note: The "Status:Running" is a unreliable message and possibly a bug in the console page rather than the actual script.  Often refreshing the console page changes the status. Even if not, I would disregard it completely.

Comment: @Marios Please have a look at the above [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65036762/script-to-search-for-multiple-unread-labels-in-gmail-threads-at-once?noredirect=1#comment114981695_65036762)

Comment: @TheMaster I was not aware of that. Does that mean it causes no issues whatsoever?

Comment: I believe so, unless it actually throws a error in the actual script editor page as well.

Comment: @TheMaster. *"Side Note: The ..."* **You seem to be [correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65036762/script-to-search-for-multiple-unread-labels-in-gmail-threads-at-once?noredirect=1#comment114981717_65036762)**. I just refreshed the page and it shows `Completed`. Thank you :)

Comment: @TheMaster and all. As a final note. Should I just omit `refreshThreads` altogether? Would it make any difference?

Comment: It's only useful if labels are changed before you access the threads. Adding a refresh as a last line doesn't make a difference, I think. Also @Tanaike Consider adding your first comment as a answer.

Comment: **Thank you all**. Also @Tanaike Please *"consider adding your first comment as an answer."* so I can accept it. You could probably add a variation with both AND as well as OR included.Not many users make it all the way down to the comments.

Comment: Thank you for replying and discussing. From your replyings, I posted it as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `" "` which is a space is used as `AND` operator.
- `OR` and `{}` can be used as `OR` operator.

Using above operators, your goal can be achieved.

- When you want to search the mails with `label:unread` and `label:00-fruit/01-apples/red`, please use the search query as follows.

  label:unread label:00-fruit/01-apples/red
- When you want to search the mails with `label:unread` and `label:00-fruit/01-apples/red` or `label:02-veggies/01-peppers/red`,  please use the search query as follows.

  ```
    label:unread (label:00-fruit/01-apples/red OR label:02-veggies/01-peppers/red)
  ```
- or

  ```
    label:unread {label:00-fruit/01-apples/red label:02-veggies/01-peppers/red}
  ```

#### Reference:

- [Search operators you can use with Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you again and sorry for the late response.