# in Gmail how to show the search result of (is:unread label:customer1) in specific Lable

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-imap

I have explored every available option using filters, but none yielded the desired outcome. Is it possible to accomplish this task using Google Apps Script? My attempts with filters were fruitless due to the limitation of not being able to select more than one label or category simultaneously.

Updates:
I need the result messages to be visible in a label called Unread, which is a sub-label of Customer1

This is the final from @Tanaike, thanks a lot for him

```js
function customer1_unread_label() {
  const customer1_label1 = "customer1"; // This label name is from your reply.
  const unreadCustomer1_label2 = "customer1/Unread customer1"; // This label name is from your reply.

  const label2 = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(unreadCustomer1_label2);
  const threads1 = GmailApp.search(`is:unread label:${customer1_label1}`);
 threads1.forEach(thread => { if (!thread.getLabels().find(l => l.getName() == unreadCustomer1_label2)) { thread.addLabel(label2); } });

  const threads2 = GmailApp.search(`is:read label:${unreadCustomer1_label2}`);
  threads2.forEach(thread => thread.removeLabel(label2));
}
```

Comment: please edit your question and include your code

Comment: If you have the label 'customer1' you can always find unread mails with 'is:unread label:customer1'. If you make folder under customer1 named 'unread' you can redirect incoming mails to it, but it WILL NOT remove read mails from there automatically. Although you can write app script to check that folder for read mails and remove them from 'unread' folder.

Comment: Have you read [Script to search for multiple unread labels in Gmail threads at once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65044983/1330560)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the messages by searching with `is:unread label:customer1`.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const threads = GmailApp.search("is:unread label:customer1");
  const res = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
  res.forEach(thread => {
    thread.forEach(message => {
      const title = message.getSubject();
      console.log(title);
    });
  });
}
```

- In this sample script, the message titles of the retrieved messages are shown in the log.
- When you want to search the multiple labels, how about the following modification?

  - From

    ```
      const threads = GmailApp.search("is:unread label:customer1");
    ```
  - To

    ```
      const threads = GmailApp.search("is:unread {label:customer1 label:customer2}");
    ```
  - In this case, the unread emails with the label `customer1` or `customer2` are retrieved. If you want `customer1` AND `customer2`, please modify to `is:unread label:customer1 label:customer2`.

#### References:

- [search(query)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#searchquery)
- [getMessagesForThreads(threads)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getmessagesforthreadsthreads)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

### Added 1:

From your following reply,

> I need the entire code to retrieve unread messages from the "customer1" label and display them in the "customer1/Unread" label. Additionally, once I read any message, it should be automatically removed from the "customer1/Unread" label. I believe triggering the code every minute would be the most suitable approach.

I understood that your actual expected request was as follows.

1. You wanted to change the label of the unread emails of `customer1` to `customer1/Unread`.
2. You wanted to change the label of the read emails of `customer1/Unread` to `customer1`.

#### Sample script:

```js
function sample2() {
  const customer1_label1 = "customer1"; // This label name is from your reply.
  const unreadCustomer1_label2 = "customer1/unread"; // This label name is from your reply.

  const [label1, label2] = [customer1_label1, unreadCustomer1_label2].map(e => GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(e));
  const threads1 = GmailApp.search(`is:unread label:${customer1_label1}`);
  threads1.forEach(thread => thread.removeLabel(label1).addLabel(label2));

  const threads2 = GmailApp.search(`is:read label:${unreadCustomer1_label2}`);
  threads2.forEach(thread => thread.removeLabel(label2).addLabel(label1));
}
```

- When this script is run, the unread emails of `customer1` are moved to `customer1/unread`. And, the read emails of `customer1/unread` is moved to `customer1`.
- From `I believe triggering the code every minute would be the most suitable approach.`, if you want to run this script with the time-driven trigger, please install it to the function.

#### Added 2:

From your following reply,

> but I need to clarify one point, I don't need to remove the unread messages from Customer1, keep it visible as it is in this label. so, if there are unread messages, they should be visible in the Customer1/Unread and once it is became read they will not be visible in Customer1/Unread, the code should not change anything in the customer1 label

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function sample2() {
  const customer1_label1 = "customer1"; // This label name is from your reply.
  const unreadCustomer1_label2 = "customer1/unread"; // This label name is from your reply.

  const label2 = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(unreadCustomer1_label2);
  const threads1 = GmailApp.search(`is:unread label:${customer1_label1}`);
  threads1.forEach(thread => thread.addLabel(label2));

  const threads2 = GmailApp.search(`is:read label:${unreadCustomer1_label2}`);
  threads2.forEach(thread => thread.removeLabel(label2));
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, sorry for my unclear inquiry,  I need the result messages to be visible in a label called Unread, which is a sub-label of Customer1

Comment: @Maarouf Alsheikh Thank you for replying. About your actual expected result of `I need the result messages to be visible in a label called Unread, which is a sub-label of Customer1`, in this case, how about modifying `const threads = GmailApp.search("is:unread label:customer1");` in my answer to `const threads = GmailApp.search("is:unread label:customer1/unread");` (or `"label:customer1/unread"`)? By this modification, the emails in the folder `customer1/unread` can be retrieved. If I misunderstood your actual expected result, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike, I appreciate your comment. I need the entire code to retrieve unread messages from the "customer1" label and display them in the "customer1/Unread" label. Additionally, once I read any message, it should be automatically removed from the "customer1/Unread" label. I believe triggering the code every minute would be the most suitable approach.

Comment: @Maarouf Alsheikh Thank you for replying. Your actual expected request is to move the unread emails from the label `customer1` to `customer1/unread`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Maarouf Alsheikh From your reply, I added one more sample script in my answer by guessing your actual expected request. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your actual expected request, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I appreciate your help, but I need to clarify one point,
I don't need to remove the unread messages from Customer1, keep it visible as it is in this label.
so, if there are unread messages, they should be visible in the Customer1/Unread and once it is became read they will not be visible in Customer1/Unread, the code should not change anything in the customer1 label

Comment: @Maarouf Alsheikh Thank you for replying. From your reply, I added one more sample script. Please confirm it.

Comment: Thanks so much, it is working like a charm,, I need if possible to add a condition before applying the command in this line, so if the label unreadCustomer1_label2 is already assigned then no need to reassign it. threads1.forEach(thread => thread.addLabel(label2)); – –

Comment: @Maarouf Alsheikh Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `if the label unreadCustomer1_label2 is already assigned then no need to reassign it`, how about modifying `threads1.forEach(thread => thread.addLabel(label2));` to `threads1.forEach(thread => { if (!thread.getLabels().find(l => l.getName() == unreadCustomer1_label2)) { thread.addLabel(label2); } });`?